# Getting data from joined query builder

Tags: php, symfony

Hello I'm currently working on menu randomizer web app. Every dish in menu has ingredients, and each ingredient has: name, unit and ammount. Dishes and Ingredients are two different entities that are in OneToMany relation. I want to query each Dish and its Ingredients so here's my custom query:

DishRepository.php

```
   /**
    * @return Dish[]
    */
    
    public function findMealsByDish($meal)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->leftJoin('d.ingredients', 'ingredients')
            ->addSelect('ingredients')
            ->where('d.type = :meal')
            ->setParameter('meal', $meal)
            ->andWhere('d.owner = :owner')
            ->setParameter('owner', $this->security->getUser())
            ->orderBy('d.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

When I `dd()` my query I get result like this: 
[image]

I've been looking for but can't find how can I access those Inredients data like: name, etc.

Comment: foreach($collection as $item){ $item->getName()... } or with getIterator foreach($arrayCollection->getIterator() as $i => $item) {//do things with $item}

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem ... Can't you use a simple foreach and access this data? Have you tried it and do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there is actually a lot easier way to do what you are trying to achieve, without any custom queries (using Doctrine and Entities properly).

From what I can see, you have a ManyToOne (or ManyToMany) relationship between meals and dishes (through dish.type). If you don't already have it, you should set the mappedBy side of the relationship on Meal. (https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony3-doctrine-relations/one-to-many).

Then to get all the dishes of a particular meal type, you only need to do:

```
$dishes = $meal->getDishes();
```

Now that you have all the dishes you need, you can simply create a foreach loop to go through each dish and get the ingredients (thanks to the OneToMany relationship).

```
foreach ($dishes as $dish){
     $ingredients = $dish->getIngredients();
     foreach( $ingredients as $ingredient) {
          //get name as $ingredient->getName();
     }
}
```

Please note that this has performance issues if you have a LOT of dishes as the database will be queried each time in the loop (read up on n+1 problem) to get the ingredients but unless you have really large number of dishes, this should not be a concern.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to make it too complicated, while there was an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ArrayCollection ([OneToMany](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)) so you need to browse the ingredients array collection and then you will have access to properties such as name, etc.

For that you can dump the first one like this :

```
 dump(yourDishArray[0]->getIngredients()[0]->getName()); //returns "butter"
```

If you need to iterate (dump all elements name's one by one for e.g) you can do something like that :

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count(yourArray[0]->getIngredients()); $i++)  { 
   dump(yourDishArray[0]->getIngredients()->[$i]->getName());
}
```

NB : You can also use a `foreach` instead